# dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "PyExc_ValueError"

Tags: python, numpy, termux

Пытаюсь запустить скрипт Telegram-бота с библиотекой на Termux. Возникает вот такая ошибка: https://pastebin.com/dxH2phhT

`Android 11`, `Termux 0.118.0`, `Python 3.11`, `Numpy 1.26.3`. Код отлично работает на в Replit. В самом коде, судя по логам, никакой ошибки нет и, похоже, есть проблема с файлами.

Что мне бросилось в глаза, это строчка:

```
from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "PyExc_ValueError" referenced by "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311.so"...
```

Нигде не смог найти решения проблемы. Благодарю за помощь заранее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема неясным для меня образом решилась.
Что я сделал:

```
$ python -m venv numpy
$ source numpy/bin/activate
```

Затем, установив `numpy` в venv, я закрыл его (`exit`) и снова попробовал запустить файл. Какого было моё удивление, что это сработало.

(Напишите в комментариях, почему это сработало. Я новичок в этом деле. Я отредактирую ответ и добавлю пояснение сюда, для других людей.)